# Join 2 dataframes based on their differences while keeping common rows and columns python

Tags: python, pandas

Context: I'm trying to add data from a new dataframe into an old dataframe where the only differences between them is that the data has been replaced with other information. I'll use an example to explain myself better:

Let's say the old dataframe has this structure:

```
test_old = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FactsEN' :['sales','price','promotion','sales','price','promotion'], 'Sales' : [12345,12,11,54321,14,12], 'Type' : ['type1','type1','type1','type2','type2','type2']})


test_new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'FactsEN' :['sales','price','new_promotion','sales','price','new_promotion'], 'Sales' : [12345,12,11,54321,14,13], 'Type' : ['type1','type1','type1','type2','type2','type2']})
```

How can I join both dataframes keeping the common columns and simply adding the differences between them? Ideally the dataframes would go from this:

```
>>> test_old
     FactsEN  Sales   Type
0      sales  12345  type1
1      price     12  type1
2  promotion     11  type1
3      sales  54321  type2
4      price     14  type2
5  promotion     12  type2

>>> test_new
         FactsEN  Sales   Type
0          sales  12345  type1
1          price     12  type1
2  new_promotion     11  type1
3          sales  54321  type2
4          price     14  type2
5  new_promotion     13  type2
```

To this:

```
         FactsEN  Sales   Type
0          sales  12345  type1
1          price     12  type1
2      promotion     11  type1
3  new_promotion     11  type1
4          sales  54321  type2
5          price     14  type2
6      promotion     12  type2
7  new_promotion     13  type2
```

I was trying concatenate and merges, but none of them managed to get the output...

```
concatenated_dataframe = pd.merge(old,new, how='outer', left_on=new.columns, right_on=old.columns)
```

Any help is very welcome!

Comment: Would you like to add the row difference based on some column or the entire row should be added in case of a difference?

Comment: Hey, I'd like to add the row difference based on the FactsEN column (essentially the variables) - The FactsEN on the new dataframe will always have differences

Comment: FactsEN  is not unique hence your merge is not working

Comment: I guess it would be based on row differences then? Not sure how I could do that

Comment: if you go by row difference, you ll get a new row `price     16  type2`

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that would work then, I'll have to see what other methods are there

Comment: we can code our custom logic to do this

Comment: I just noticed my dataframe had inconsistent data, I just updated it, but still, I'll have to see which could work then

Comment: Hi @ROO I have provided an answer with your approach let me know if it helps and if you have any doubts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use [`pandas.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and join on multiple columns.

```
pd.merge(test_old, test_new, on=['FactsEN',  'Sales',   'Type'], how="outer")
```

This gives us the expected data

```
         FactsEN  Sales   Type
0          sales  12345  type1
1          price     12  type1
2      promotion     11  type1
3          sales  54321  type2
4          price     14  type2
5      promotion     12  type2
6  new_promotion     11  type1
7  new_promotion     13  type2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and then drop duplicates:

```
pd.concat([test_old, test_new], ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```